# (n,r)-Cat of (n,r) categories

Tags: higher-category-theory

The category of (n,r) categories is an (n+1, r+1) category (n,r)-Cat; where objects are (n,r) categories, morphisms are (n,r) functors, and k-morphisms for k>=2 are (k-1) transfors. I seem to know this but have not understood the idea; like how it is getting enhanced to (n+1,r+1) and how transfors are arising here. Could someone explain this category to me?

Comment: Have you understood low-dimensional versions, like the 2-category of 1-categories?

Comment: Cat is the 2 category where we take the small categories as objects, the usual 1-morphisms are functors, and natural transformations between the functors as 2-morphisms.

Comment: Ok, that's a good start.  How about the [3-category of 2-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2Cat)?

Comment: Here the objects are 2-categories, 2 functors are 1-morphisms, 2-morphisms are lax natural transformations, and 3-morphisms are modifications. Here, the k-morphisms are morphisms between (k-1)-morphisms, and the transfors associating j-morphisms to (j+k)-morphisms were not clear to me. But now, I guess I have understood what it means to associate morphisms up in degree by k. For example, for lax natural transformations, we have 1-morphism $\alpha_{A}$ in D corresponding to object A in C and  2-morphism $\alpha_f$ in D corresponding to 1-morphism f in C; thus shifted in degree by 1. Is this ok?

Comment: But, I still have a couple of doubts. Where do the 2-morphisms in C go over to D? Also, why do we not add perturbations between the modifications for 2-Cat (three-category of two categories)? Thanks.

Comment: The morphisms in C that would go to "one above" the highest dimension of D go instead to "equations".  (You can think of D as an (n+1)-category whose (n+1)-morphisms are all equalities.)  For instance, in an ordinary natural transformation, the objects go to morphisms and the morphisms go to naturality squares.  Similarly, in a lax natural transformation, each 2-cell goes to a "cylinder" equation.  And in a modification, each object goes to a 2-cell and each morphism goes to a different kind of cylinder equation.

Comment: When you run out of dimensions, there's nothing left to go to: a modification doesn't send a 2-cell to anything.  Similarly, there's no room for perturbations in 2-Cat, since it would send an object to a 3-cell, but there aren't any.

Comment: Thanks, dear. Why there is no perturbation can also be stated as, I guess, there are no 4-morphisms in 2-Cat which can only serve as 3-transfors (perturbations). Is this correct?

Comment: I would say "there are no 4-morphisms in 2-Cat" is just the same statement as "there are no perturbations between 2-categories", not an explanation of it.  The explanation would be that there are no 3-morphisms *in* a particular 2-category.

Comment: Now I understand dear. Thanks.

Comment: I've summarized the discussion below as an answer.  (FYI, "dear" is not a usual thing to say in English in this context.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Summarizing the discussion from the comments.)*  It's useful to start with low-dimensional examples, such as:

- In the 2-category of 1-categories,

  - the objects are categories
  - the morphisms are functors (0-transfors, which take objects to objects and morphisms to morphisms)
  - the 2-cells are natural transformations (1-transfors, which take objects to morphisms).
- In the 3-category of 2-categories

  - the objects are 2-categories
  - the morphsims are functors
  - the 2-cells are possibly-lax/pseudo natural transformations (1-transfors, which take objects to morphisms, and morphisms to 2-cell witnesses of naturality)
  - the 3-cells are modifications (2-transfors, which take objects to 2-cells)

In general, a $k$-transfor increases dimensions by $k$, taking $j$-cells in the domain to $(j+k)$-cells in the codomain.

If $j+k = n+1$, the codomain $n$-category has no $(j+k)$-cells as such, but we can consider "equations" as such cells (i.e. regard an $n$-category as an $(n+1)$-category having only identity $(n+1)$-cells).  For instance, a natural transformation "takes morphisms to equations", namely naturality equations.  Similarly, a lax/pseudo natural transformation takes 2-cells to "cylinder" equations, and a modification takes morphisms to a different kind of cylinder equation.

If $j+k > n+1$, there is nothing nontrivial for a $j$-cell to go to under a $k$-transfor, since an $n$-category has at most $n$-cells.  Similarly, if $k>n$ there is no room for a (nonidentity) $k$-transfor between $n$-categories as there is nothing for it to even send objects to.